# Can't connect to google cloud sql from server

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've created sql instance on google cloud platform,and I have an existing live wordpress website sitting on a server, I have added the website ip address to the instance connection authorised networks. I even added 0.0.0.0/0 to allow all networks to connect.

The problem is I can connect to the instance database from my local machine weather with my mysql client or with my local website. But I can't connect with the same credentials on my live website.

```
define('DB_HOST', '35.242.xxx.xxx'); // gcloud sql db ip address
```

Could it be because my website has a shared ip address?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone faces the same issue I solved it by adding the instance ip address to my cpanel remote mysql and also whitelist the ip address.

Comment: yes adding google ip by `csf -a x.x.x.x`solved my problem